# How to get value from ParameterExpression?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a method with the following signature:

```
void Method(Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>>> collectionSelector) {}
```

I need to get the result value of `collectionSelector` in order to compare the result with another instance of `IEnumerable<TCollection>`. I'm trying to achieve my objective as in the code below, but I got stuck while I was asked to provide parameter value:

```
var collectionSelectorFunc = collectionSelector.Compile();
var collection = collectionSelectorFunc.Invoke(collectionSelector.Parameters[0]./*???*/);
```

How to put there the actual value of the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no value because a parameter is a placeholder. A parameter represents a method argument (lambda argument in this case). You can call this function/expression with *any* value. There is no pre-set value.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. However, there exists a runtime value for each possible argument. Is there any callback for such case? Could I react when the collectionSelector is invoked from elsewhere with the specific argument provided?

Comment: @yBee I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. I think you should ask another question and explain in detail what exactly do you need and why. An example wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: You can post a link to the question here if you want. Note, that an Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>>> is conceptually similar to a Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>>. You understand that you can invoke a Func with one argument only if you provide an argument. The Func *is* the callback, and inside of it (in its body) you can look at the concrete argument.

Comment: I understand now. The `Method` is responsible for providing values for all ParameterExpressions. Therefore to solve my issue I need to provide the Method with another parameter - `IEnumerable<TSource> source`. Then each ParameterExpression value from `collectionSelector` would be taken from that `source` and I would be able to produce `IEnumerable<TCollection>` for each.